# Why does Euguene say, in the beginning of Tangled, that this is the story of how he died?

Tags: tangled

The movie *Tangled* begins with a monologue by Flynn/Eugene.

> This is the story of how I died.
>
> Don't worry! This is actually very fun story.
>
> And the truth is, it isn't even mine.

But he doesn't die in the film. Is there any reason why he says this?

Comment: Why do you keep insisting that Eugene didn't die? It's a major plot point AND the climax scene of the film, where he TRADES HIS LIFE for Rapunzel's reedom. This is very clear...

Comment: @Duthomhas haha I was not insisting, I just did not realize he died... It didn't even occur to me.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

He died when Mother Gothel stabbed him. Rapunzel's tear brought him back to life.

> “And you were mine, too.” Rapunzel leaned toward Flynn as **he closed his eyes.**
>
> Desperately, she began to sing. She wanted to bring forth some bit of magic from her shorn hair to save him. But the magic was gone with her hair.
>
> Distraught, Rapunzel could not hold back her grief. She wept, cradling
> Flynn’s limp body.
>
> A single golden tear fell on his cheek.
>
> Flynn stirred. Though she didn’t know it, Rapunzel did have one last
> bit of magic left deep inside her, and it was contained in that single
> golden tear. Flynn’s eyes fluttered open.
>
> <sub><sup>[Tangled: Official Novelisation](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/9411598-tangled)</sup></sub>

and

> Rapunzel looked at Flynn. "Don’t go. Stay with me, Eugene.”
> He touched her check. “You were my new dream.”
> **He closed his eyes, and Rapunzel began to weep. Flynn was gone!**
> A single golden tear fell upon his check. Then the tear - and Flynn's
> entire body - began to glow.
> Flynn was healed. “Rapunzel?" The two shared their first kiss.
>
> <sub><sup>[Tangled: Book and CD](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/9480470-tangled-read-along-storybook-and-cd)</sup></sub>

and

> Mother Gothel stabs him. As Flynn lies dying, Mother Gothel gives Rapunzel a choice - freedom or Flynn. Of course, Rapunzel chooses Flynn but he cuts her magical hair before she can save him! Instantly, Rapunzel's hair loses its power and Mother Gothel turns to dust. **Rapunzel is free at last, but at the cost of Flynn's life.** Brokenhearted, Rapunzel weeps and a single tear touches Flynn - he lives!
>
> <sub><sup>[Tangled: The Essential Guide](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/9413803-tangled)</sup></sub>

and

> Flynn was growing pale. He smiled
> weakly as I knelt beside him. ‘You were my
> new dream," he said. “And you were mine,” I answered.
>
> **His eyes closed. He was gone.**
>
> He had sacrificed himself to give me my freedom. Without my magical hair, without Mother Gothel, I could go anywhere and do anything. But it was all meaningless without Flynn. I tried to sing, desperately hoping to find a trace of magic in my hair. But I had nothing left to give. I bent my head, and a single tear fell on Flynn’s face. The spot where it fell began to
> glow.
>
> I watched, barely able to breathe. Hope was growing bright inside me
> as the magical glow spread over Flynn’s face, his hands, his arms. The
> last of my healing magic was in that single tear. The color returned to his face. The grip of his hand grew firm again. At last, his eyes flickered open.
>
> <sub><sup>[Rapunzel's Tale](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/10121229-rapunzel-s-tale)</sup></sub>

Comment: I suppose this is the most plausible explanation, but is there any other instance where it is established her powers are strong enough to bring someone back from the dead?

Comment: @Wade - He said that he died. I can't think of another instance where her powers are shown to be capable of resurrection, but this one instance seems pretty conclusive, having seen her repeatedly youthen Mother Gothel and heal Flynn

Comment: It might be worth noting that the definition of death, and thereby determination of such, has been fluid through the ages. There was a time when your heart stopping was considered that you had died, and that if people got it restarted, then you have come back from the dead. That likely would have been the criteria in a medieval setting as in *Tangled*.

Comment: @Wade Him dying is what makes that whole scene matter.  He's dead, the situation is hopeless, nothing can be done, and the only possible solution is magic.  But magic is gone, and Flynn says a poignant thing and goes limp and Rapunzel cries in despair - classic movie death.  But then magic tear / true love / etc brings him back.  It's basically the whole point of the scene, even aside from him actually saying he died.

Answer (score 0):

I think the opening line was intended to encompass multiple meanings, such as referencing the Star Wars-esque plot element where Flynn Rider the thief died and Eugene Fitzherbert took his place. In the conversation after their boat ride, Rapunzel said she liked Eugene better than Flynn. New Eugene chose to repent his ways and relinquish the crown to his two former partners. His old dream of being "surrounded by enormous piles of money" while "alone" figuratively died, replaced by his "new dream" of Rapunzel, such as making sure Rapunzel can finally start her "life" without the witch. He said if she healed him, she would "die" too, figuratively. Eugene prevented this by cutting her hair just before falling unconscious.

(I personally don't believe that Eugene died literally)